# Create HTTP post request and receive response in C# application and parsing the response

Tags: c#, http, cgi, http-post

I am trying to write a C# program which posts http form to a CGI script and obtains a response.

The response is web page which needs to be parsed as I need only a certain portion of it.

Is there any way I can obtain the response web page and parse it in C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["foo"] = "bar";
            values["bar"] = "baz";
            var url = "http://foo.bar/baz.cgi";
            byte[] result = client.UploadValues(url, values);

            // TODO: do something with the result
            // for example if it represents text you could
            // convert this byte array into a string using the proper
            // encoding: string sResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My internet connection is slow and it takes a few seconds to submit the form and receive the response. How can I handle this in the code?

Comment: The code throws 3 errors and a warning: Warning 1 The using directive for 'System.Net' appeared previously in this namespace
Error 2 'System.Net.WebClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' 
Error 4 'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'UploadValues' and no extension method 'UploadValues' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JeswinSimon, which version of .NET are you using? As far as the slowness of your internet connection is concerned, well, there's not much you could do from code about it :-) You will have to contact your ISP provider.

Comment: .net 4. Windows phone 7 C# application. About the internet connection speed, is there anyway I can handle it using "UploadValuesCompleted" ?

Comment: @JeswinSimon, in WP7 you only have the async version of the methods. So you should subscribe to the `UploadValuesCompleted` event and then use the `UploadValuesAsync` to trigger the request.

Comment: @JeswinSimon, remove the `using` clause from the `WebClient` declaration and then replace the synchronous `UploadValues` method call with the asynchronous `UploadValuesAsync` method after having subscribed for the `UploadValuesCompleted` event.

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["foo"] = "foo";
            values["bar"] = "bar";
            var url = "http://foo.bar/baz.cgi";
            byte[] result = client.UploadValuesasync(url, values);
            
     
        }`

Comment: Is this the right code ?(without the event handler) Again it throws two errors: _The type or namespace name 'NameValueCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_ and _'System.Net.WebClient' does not contain a definition for 'UploadValuesasync' and no extension method 'UploadValuesasync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.WebClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Comment: @JeswinSimon, it seems that UploadValuesAsync method doesn't exist for Windows Phone 7. You will have to use some of the other available methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.96).aspx

Comment: Can the `UploadStringAsync` method be used to upload multiple values?

Comment: @JeswinSimon, yes, but you will have to manually format and url encode the string that you are passing as argument. For example: `"foo=bar&bar=baz"`. It is up to you to ensure that the `bar` and `baz` values are properly url encoded.

Comment: Getting a new error on `byte[] result = client.UploadStringAsync(url, str);` _Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'byte[]'_ Should i declare `result` as a string ?

Comment: @JeswinSimon, asynchronous methods do not return values. You must subscribe to the `UploadStringCompleted` event. It is inside this event that you will get the result.

Comment: Can the same method be applied for serverlets and php ?

Comment: `<form action="mypage.php" method="POST" name="pass"  onSubmit="return validate_pass(this)">` . I can use the code for this form by changing only the url ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `WebClient` for sending the form and retrieving the response and [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for parsing the result for this task.